# V9 - Converter de VB para C# Importar registos Contabilidade

Tags: c#

Bom dia,

Estou a tentar converter um programita que fiz de VB para c#.
Estou com dificuldades em tratar do cabeçalho.
Em vb é simples.

```
Dim Doc As New CblBEDocumento
Dim Mov As CblBELinhaDocGeral
Doc.Ano = 2010
```

etc..
Em C# resumido

```
CblBEDocumento CblDoc = new CblBEDocumento();
CblBELinhaDocGeral MovCbl = new CblBELinhaDocGeral();
resultado = Plataforma.Consulta("Select `from " + tab_tmp + " order by ano, mes ASC");
if (resultado.Vazia())
 {
 Printa("Não tem movimentos de contabilidade para processar!");
  }
else
{
while (!resultado.NoFim())
{
Ano = resultado.Valor("Ano");
Mes = resultado.Valor("Mes");
Dia = resultado.Valor("Dia");
Data_Mov = resultado.Valor("Data_Mov");
Conta_Mov = resultado.Valor("Conta_Mov");
Descritivo = resultado.Valor("Descricao");
Diario = resultado.Valor("Diario");
Debito = resultado.Valor("Val_Deb");
Credito = resultado.Valor("Val_Cred");
CblDoc.set_Ano(Ano);
```

Mas quando tento fazer o `CblDoc.Ano = '2010';` ele não reconhece a existencia de CblDoc.Ano.
Não tenho a opção de mexer no campo do objecto.
O CblDoc.set_Ano espera uma referencia, não me parece que seja desta maneira.
Como é que se usa este objecto em C#?
Obrigado,

José Rui

Comment: Olá estás a tentar converter VB.net para C#? Também ajuda colocar mais detalhes na questão, mais detalhes aumenta a probabilidade de obter ajuda desejada.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/objects

Comment: Estranho mesmo é a atribuição em aspas simples, ai é aspas duplas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá,
Penso que estás a referir-te à v9 em que usas os interops.
A atribuição dos valores, neste caso, é da seguinte forma:

```
CblDoc.set_Ano(2019);
```

Comment: Bom dia, Sim, estava a falar dos interops. Tentei usar o set_Ano, mas ele não me estava a aceitar o valor que meti lá. Vou testar essa atribuição.

Answer (score 0):

Suas propriedades estão publicas ?

exemplo :

```
public class CblBEDocumento { 
       public string ano { get; set;} 
 }
```

Comment: Pode ser asneira minha, mas como o objecto está predefinido e não por mim, por norma eu não lhe mexo nas propriedades

Comment: Entendo, mas você precisa saber se essas propriedades estão publicas, ou se nelas existem os get's e set's da classe. 
Sem essas informações nao conseguimos lhe ajudar.

Comment: Esse o meu principal problema, ainda estou a migrar e ainda não penso c# nem completamente oop, portanto a instaciação por vezes não entra no meu casco.